# How to set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header on an AWS S3 object using Ruby SDK?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How do you set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header of an S3 object using version 1 of the AWS SDK for Ruby. The [docs here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/S3Object.html#write-instance_method) show how to set a variety of headers, but there doesn't seem to be anything for the access control header. It does mention a `:metadata` option, but that prefixes the values with `x-amz-meta`, which is not what I'm looking for.

The reason I ask is because I'm trying to download a publicly readable file in S3 (which I put there) by making an Ajax call from Javascript. I have set the ACL to public read, which means I can view it in a browser, but I get the `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` error from the Ajax call.

Comment: did you enable [cors](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html) on your bucket ?

Comment: Well, is that the only way to do it? Is there any way to set the header for a specific object, without applying it to all objects in the bucket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Well, is that the only way to do it?

Yes, that's the only way to do it.  CORS in S3 is only configurable at the bucket level.

Comment: Grand, I created a separate bucket and configured CORS. Actually, I think this works out better. This way, I can restrict to all my sub domains e.g. `https://*.mydomain.com` whereas the original header doesn't allow that.